# attachment field in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, attachment

I want to alter a table and create a new field with the type Attachment.

First I thought of the following:

```
Dim SQL_Attachement_Str As String
SQL_Attachement_Str = "ALTER TABLE tbl_FinalTable_summerized ADD CoCAttachement ATTACHMENT"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL_Attachement_Str
```

But unfortunately (in my case) this is not possible.

My second attempt was it to first create the field as a TEXT type and then later change the type into Attachment as the following:

```
Dim SQL_Attachement_Str As String
SQL_Attachement_Str = "ALTER TABLE tbl_FinalTable_summerized ADD CoCAttachement TEXT"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL_Attachement_Str

Dim tbl As TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tbl = db.TableDefs("tbl_FINALtable_Summerized")
tbl.Fields("CoCAttachement").Type = dbAttachment

Set tbl = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

So What I need is a way to add a field with the type Attachment to the table

thank you people :D

Comment: don't use text fields for binary data. text fields are subject to characterset translation rules and validation. binary data can/will contain byte sequences that are invalid for whatever collation/charset the field's using, and can/will get corrupted.

Comment: So how would I do it? 
Can I transform a different field type into an attachment?

Comment: Why is a code solution needed for this? Is the designer unacceptable for some reason?

Comment: It should be automated. That is the problem. My idea is to write everything in a module and then run it. The requirement to that project is that one does not have to make adjustments by hand

Comment: `db.tbldefs("tbl...").createfield("CoCAtt..",dblongbinary)`

Comment: what would this be equal to? I assume that there has to be an equality?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't appending data, just adding a field you could always just keep it simple and add the field in design view, no?

You just inspired some research.

```
currentdb.TableDefs("Table").CreateField("Attachment",dblongbinary)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845510.aspx

Comment: You cannot replace TEXT with Attachment. It gives an erros.

Comment: Try `OLE Object` then?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is searching for an answer to this question, this does the trick:

```
Dim fld As DAO.Field

Set fld = CurrentDb().TableDefs("MyTable").CreateField("NewField", 101&)
CurrentDb().TableDefs("MyTable").Fields.Append fld
CurrentDb().TableDefs.Refresh

Set fld = Nothing
```

FieldType values for other complex data types can be found here:
http://allenbrowne.com/func-DAO.html#FieldTypeName